# PyQt4 rich text editor WYSIWYG toolbar to set basic text properties

Tags: python, richtextbox, pyqt, wysiwyg, pyqt4

I'm using PyQT4 to create a little GUI that allows people in my lab to write notes about physiological experiments. Right now I've got plain text editing going but it would be nice if the user could use rich text editing to set the currently selected text's font properties, bold/italic/font/font size would be sufficient. I am specifically looking for a ready-made component that would connect to and control a QTextEdit. If adding images was supported that would be even better. I am looking for something no more fancy than stackoverflow's javascript wysiwyg rich text editor which I am using to write this question, but in PyQT4, obviously.

I could program this toolbar myself, however I am sure someone has already done this, yet Google has been unhelpful. If not something ready-made, then at least a stub I could copy-paste snippets of. Thanks!

Comment: I've looked before as well and not found anything. Like you say though, shouldn't be too hard to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

I have a WIP one in my OpenWorld software: http://traipse.assembla.com/wiki/show/open-world It's far from complete and could probably be done better. It's GPL v2

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/demos-textedit.html).

Of course it is in C++ but Qt/Python is pretty similar to Qt/C++.